# mongocxx crash when doing many inserts & catching exceptions in underlying C driver

Tags: mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver, mongo-c-driver

I have a C++ application which is processing JSON and inserting into DB. It's doing a pretty simple insert, parses the JSON adds a couple of fields and inserts as below.

I have also surrounded the call with a try/catch to handle any exceptions that might be thrown.

The application is probably processing around 360-400 records a minute.

It has been working quite well however it occasionally errors and crashes. Code and stack trace below.

**Code**

```
try {
    bsoncxx::builder::basic::document builder;
    builder.append(bsoncxx::builder::basic::concatenate(bsoncxx::from_json(jsonString)));
    builder.append(bsoncxx::builder::basic::kvp(std::string("created"), bsoncxx::types::b_date(std::chrono::system_clock::now())));

    bsoncxx::document::value doc = builder.extract();

    bsoncxx::stdx::optional<mongocxx::result::insert_one> result = m_client[m_dbName][std::string("Data")].insert_one(doc.view());

    if (!result) {
        m_log->warn(std::string("Insert failed."), label);
    }
} catch (...) {
    m_log->warn(std::string("Insert failed and threw exception."), label);
}
```

**Stack**
[image: Stack trace]

So I guess I have two questions. Any ideas as to why it is crashing? And is there some way I can catch and handle this error in such a way that it does crash the application.

mongocxx version is: 3.3.0

mongo-c version is: 1.12.0

Any help appreciated.

**Update 1**
I did some profiling on the DB and although its doing a high amount of writes in performing quite well and all operations are using indexes. Most inefficient operation takes 120ms so I don't think its a performance issue on that end.

**Update 2**
After profiling with valgrind I was unable to find any allocation errors. I then used perf to profile CPU usage and have found over time CPU usage builds up. Typically starting at around 15% base load when the process first starts and then ramping up of the course of 4 or 5 hours until the crash occurs with CPU usage around 40 - 50%. During this whole time the number of DB operations per second remains consistent at 10 per second.

To rule out the possibility of other processing code causing this I removed all DB handling and ran process over night and CPU usage remained flat lined at 15% the entire time.

I'm trying a few other strategies to try and identify root cause now. Will update if I find anything.

**Update 3** 
I believe I have discovered cause of this issue. After the insert process there is also an update which pushes two items onto an array using the $push operator. It does this for different records up to 18,000 times before that document is closed. The fact it was crashing on the insert under high CPU load was a bit of a red-herring.

The CPU usage build up is that process taking longer to execute as the array within document being pushed to gets longer. I re-architected to use Redis and only insert into mongodb once all items to be pushed into array are received. This flat lined CPU usage. Another way around this could be to insert each item into a temporary collection and use aggregation with $push to compile single record with array once all items to be push are received.

Graphs below illustrate issue with using $push on document as array gets longer. The huge drops are when all records are received and new documents are created for next set of items.

[image: CPU Usage]
[image: Operation Execution Time]

In closing this issue I'll take a look over on MongoDB Jira and see if anyone has reported this issue with the $push operator and if not report it myself in case this something that can be improved in future releases.

Comment: First step is to run your application under valgrind: crashes inside the memory allocator most often indicate a logic error either in your code or the driver, valgrind should help you figure out which.